# REFERER using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, referer

I have php files that i do not want users to be directly access by typing in the URL, therefore I have hidden these using .htaccess. However I want the user to be passed on (referred) to the next php file once they have logged in.

e.g. 123.456.789:8080/one.php is the login page and the user will then be sent to 123.456.789:8080/two.php.

Below is an example of some code that i found on here, but have not been able to make it work for my variables, and the fact I have the IP address and port no. Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?site\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule (^|/)B\.php(/|$) - [F,NC]
```

Comment: do you have this line of code `Options +FollowSymLinks` on top of .htaccess?

Comment: referer is incredibly unreliable, and you should not be using it as your only security mechanism. it is trivial to forge.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, wise words. Plan B= to give each user a number when they are logged in, this is then checked on feline.php, and therefore they can only access this file once the two numbers match. Any suggestions how i go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php for the logon can you not use something like this?

```
if( $logged_in){
    header("Location: http://somesite/two.php");
}
```

Comment: i am currently redirected users using the header(location), however, i want to prevent the user accessing the file directly by typing in the URL e.g 123.456.789/fileone.php. Plan B= to give each user a number when they are logged in, this is then checked on feline.php, and therefore they can only access this file once the two numbers match. Any suggestions how i go about this? Thanks